# How to update RecyclerView's data dynamiclly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some tables in the database, every table has many rows,I want to show the tables's data in a list, so I use a RecyclerView to show the data, and a spinner to select the table which I want to show.

But now, when I select an item of spinner, the RecyclerView doesn't have any changes ,it can't show the new data only after I reopen the fragment.

My code:

- In adapter：

1.`removeItem`  works

the item in the RecyclerView will be removed when `removeItem` called.

```
public void removeItem(WordCls wordCls) {
    int position = wordsList.indexOf(wordCls);
    wordsList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

2.`updateList` doesn't work

But when `updateList` called,nothing happened in the view

```
public void updateList(List<WordCls> wordsList) {
    //this.wordsList = wordsList;
    this.wordsList.clear();
    this.wordsList.addAll(wordsList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

- In fragment:

in `onCreateView()`:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.wordbook_recycler_list);  
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());  
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
wordsList = WordsManager.getWordsList(tableName); 
wordCardAdapter = new WordCardAdapter(activity, tableName, wordsList);  
recyclerView.setAdapter(wordCardAdapter);
wordCardAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new WordCardAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, WordCls wordCls) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), wordCls.getWord(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wordCardAdapter.removeItem(wordCls);
        WordsManager.deleteWord(tableName, wordCls.getWord());
    }
});
```

in `SpinnerItemSelectedListener`:

```
@Override  
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {  
    tableName= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 
    prefEditorSettings.putInt(KEY_SPINNER_SELECTED_ITEM, position);
    prefEditorSettings.commit();
    tableName = getWordbookList().get(spnSelectedPosition);
    wordsList = WordsManager.getWordsList(tableName);
    wordCardAdapter.updateList(wordsList);
    Toast.makeText(activity, tableName, 2000).show();   
}
```

==============================================
update:

the method `updateList` is right.

just my careless to have passed a wrong param at

```
tableName = getWordbookList().get(spnSelectedPosition);
```

it should be

```
tableName = getWordbookList().get(position);
```

now, it works.

Comment: providing More code will help understanding

Comment: @AkshayBhat I update the description :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't know if RecyclerView is the best way to fulfill your purpose.
RecyclerView(s) are to be used when you have to show multiple instances of your List, in a list-y way :)

If you have just one View to update (that contains multiple fields to be updated), I'd choose some data-binding library like [RoboBinding](http://robobinding.github.io/RoboBinding/getting_started.html) or the new beta version of [google binding library](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) (MVVM paradigm)

I'm not going into further details as I just want to warn you about MVVM programming paradigm that can be a worthy solution in your case.

Comment: I have some tables in the database,every table has many rows,I want to show the tables's data in a list,so I use a RecyclerView to show the data,and a spinner to select the table which I want to show.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `wordCardAdapter.updateList(wordsList)` , add new data to wordsList and `wordCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside spinner

hope it works.

Comment: can you show me your code while setting your adaptor to recyclerView

Comment: ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>;  //add string to data  RecyclerView.Adapter mAdaptor=new MyAdaptor(data);  mRecyclerView.setAdaptor(mAdaptor);



//onUpdate  ArrayList<String> new_data=new ArrayList<String>;  //add new values to data  data.addAll(new_data);  mAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thank you very much,I don't know why I can't post my code in the comment.I add the code "setting my adaptor to recyclerView" in my question description,please have a see.And about your code,I can't understand the difference from mine.Can you say some detail?Sorry for my English

Comment: replace codes inside spinner with   @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,long id) {
tableName= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 prefEditorSettings.putInt(KEY_SPINNER_SELECTED_ITEM, position);
 prefEditorSettings.commit(); 
tableName = getWordbookList().get(spnSelectedPosition); 
new_wordsList = WordsManager.getWordsList(tableName);
this.wordsList.addAll(new_wordsList);
this.wordCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(activity, tableName, 2000).show();
}

Comment: thanks,I found my error:I forgot change the `tableName = getWordbookList().get(spnSelectedPosition);`to `tableName = getWordbookList().get(position);` after I changed some code here.I was very careless,sorry for my careless,and thank you for your help